# rvm wrapper only works for non bundled gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

I am trying to create a rvm wrapper for unicorn_rails, but it has to be on a per gemset basis due to multiple apps running on a server with different unicorn versions.  After a few google searches, I've come to the conclusion that the only way to do this is to run `gem install unicorn --version x` from the rvm gemset and then create the wrapper.  Is there anyway to create a wrapper for a bundled gem?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Ok.  I figured it out, but this solution seems a bit hacky.

```
gem install unicorn
rvm wrapper ruby-version@gemset test unicorn_rails
vi `which test_unicorn_rails`
```

change the line `exec unicorn_rails '$@'` to `exec bundle exec unicorn_rails '$@'`

```
gem uninstall unicorn
```

I just submitted a [patch](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/pull/1252) to rvm to allow for `rvm wrapper ruby-version@gemset test "bundle exec unicorn_rails"` which creates `test_bundle_exec_unicorn_rails`.